# Replacing Windows 8 with Ubuntu 12.10 on an Ideapad U510

Tags: installation, lenovo, windows-8, ssd, ideapad

I have (very) recently purchased a new Lenovo Ideapad U510 with a 24 gb SSD, and was quite disappointed with Windows 8. So I am considering replacing it with Ubuntu 12.10. I have some experience in the past with Ubuntu and Mint, and it has always been simple to install or make partitions - but I've been hearing things about the secure boot feature preventing this. At least without taking extra steps. What exactly do I need to do? I've also been hearing about Samsung laptops being bricked because of installing other OSes. Is that the case with Lenovos too? I just want to make sure, as I don't want to risk ruining my laptop's hardware. Thanks.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/44179

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bricking a computer by installing an OS on it is *extremely* rare, and the issues with the Samsung laptops are the first time that I have ever heard about it.  Unless you purchase a recent Samsung laptop, you are highly unlikely to ever encounter this issue.  Regarding Secure Boot, the Linux Foundation fixed this recently by creating a bootloader signed with Microsoft's key, so you have little to worry about.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was a little too worried. Just making sure I am not going to be messing anything up.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly any pc could be "bricked" when reinstalling an OS. I'm sure I've bricked and fixed my laptops about 4+ times at least in the past 3 years installing and uninstalling OS's. If you want to be extra safe make a clone of your harddrive in case of any issues. Create a boot USB and boot to USB and 'try Ubuntu' first. If everything functions properly install ubuntu as a dual-boot alongside Win8. Ubuntu will automatically create the partitions you need and resize Win8 safely.

I'm going to say one thing though. 24gb is extremely small to be running Windows... let alone a dual-boot system. Consider upgrading your harddrive.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a Solid State drive along with a 750gb HDD. I am planning on formatting my HDD since I don't see the need of Windows - Ubuntu has everything I needed on my old laptops, and even steam, and getting Ubuntu on the SSD. Then use the HDD for the data. Can I mess up the hardware in the process? I don't mind messing up Windows though. I have everything backed up elsewhere.

Comment: *My laptop has a built in 750 gb hdd and a 24 gb ssd

Comment: A failed installation and bricking are two *very* different things.  A failed installation just means that the installation is corrupted, and can be "fixed" by re-attempting the installation.  Bricking on the other hand, is hardware damage that usually renders the motherboard useless.

Comment: I'm assuming it's safe to format my HDD with gparted, (ridding of Windows 8 in the process) and then install Ubuntu on my Solid State, right? That's all I'm really asking.